# Start again with homestead install

Tags: macos, homestead

I have got myself in a muddle with homestead on OSX. I installed homestead using the instructions here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead which said to do the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead
```

Everything was working until I wanted to add a new site. I added the site to .homestead file

```
sites:
    - map: example1.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/example1/public
    - map: example2.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/example2/public
```

I was getting homestead command not found and after some searches thought it might be because 5 docs doesn't use the global homestead install shown in 4.2 http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead. So I performed the global install. Destroyed all vagrant boxes. Ran homestead up but it failed saying another box had that name. Ended up deleting the folder I had originally created with the git clone and now when I run homestead up I get

```
VBoxManage: error: Could not rename the directory '/Users/me/VirtualBox VMs/settler_default_1430450956915_11366_1430600021875_36184' to '/Users/me/VirtualBox VMs/homestead' to save the settings file (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "SaveSettings()" at line 2788 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong or show me how to uninstall it so I can start a fresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the folder from `VirtualBox VMs` or removing it from the VirtualBox app somehow do not remove the box from vagrant.

To completely uninstall the box, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27303779/3747600) works for me.

use `vagrant global-status` to get the list of Vagrant environments, and find the `id` of the box you are going to delete, then run `vagrant destroy [id]` to remove it.