# Homestead "No input file specified" laravel 5

Tags: php, vagrant, laravel-5, homestead

Been trying this for days! I am aware there are other Qs about this, which I have checked over an over. I have one site working and the other not.

I'm using Homestead with Laravel 5 and OSX 10.10.3

I have this .yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"

memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Sites/LaraCode
      to: /home/vagrant/LaraCode

sites:
    - map: myapp.app
      to: /home/vagrant/LaraCode/myapp/public
    - map: newapp.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/LaraCode/newapp/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Both are Laravel 5 apps in these folders:

```
/Users/USERNAME/Sites/LaraCode/myapp
/Users/USERNAME/Sites/LaraCode/newapp
```

myapp.app works fine but newapp.dev gives an error:

```
No input file specified
```

in the browser.

I have chmod777 the storage folder. There is an index.php in the public folder. I vagrant provision after changes.

Homestead seems to have been a horrible waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

For me `homestead destroy` and another `homestead up` worked. Also I guess you added the new url to you hosts file, correct?

Although I agree that the docs for homestead are a little lacking.

Comment: Now lost the site I had running.

Comment: what version of homestead are you running? In 2.0 you should have a homestead destroy, and it does kill you database, but you should have a migration. vagrant destroy probably deletes the whole box.

Comment: did you re-add the box to vagrant?

Comment: Wait, your box is there but you can not get to your site? Can you run homestead up? Please provide more info.

Comment: hallelujah! Praise [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993903/a-virtualbox-machine-with-the-name-homestead-already-exists) . I had a previous homestead running, messing things up. I appreciate your input though. Sorry for lack of info but was losing it a bit there.

Comment: I agree documentation is confusing. Now I need to use homestead commands instead of Vagrant ones.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,I finally found an answer for this. I believe I had two homesteads set up, so I had to [remove a homestead from the VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993903/a-virtualbox-machine-with-the-name-homestead-already-exists)

I also had to do [update my bash_profile](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/homestead-20-setup) so I could use the homestead commands.

Afterwards, in the homestead folder I ran:

```
homestead provision
```

To ensure the yaml file was up-to-date.

All is good now. Both sites are running. Server set-ups are always a nightmare for the less computer techie developers. Where I was caught out was the lack of clear folder guidance on where to execute command lines, hence the conflicting homesteads.