# Laravel "Homestead Up" doesn't boot vm after updating VirtualBox and Vagrant says it already exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, development-environment, laravel-5.1, homestead

I was having a few issues with Homestead 2.x suddenly for reasons I don't understand.  So I took this opportunity to updated Homestead to 2.1.8, installed the latest Vagrant and VirtualBox from a suggestion off Laravel's forum, and now it seems to want to boot, but it says:

```
$ homestead up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
A VirtualBox machine with the name 'homestead' already exists.
Please use another name or delete the machine with the existing
name, and try again.
```

I'm not sure why it is sayng laravel/homestead already exists, and I'm a bit afraid to play around with this now as I don't want to delete anything.  I looked at the VirtualBox GUI and it only has one Homestead box, and a settler_default_12314848585938 box (which I don't know what that is, but it doesn't have any shared folders).  So there is no [other VirtualBox running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993903/a-virtualbox-machine-with-the-name-homestead-already-exists).

I found these and a few others, but they are dated and unrelated in that I'm not running 2.0.x, but 2.1.x.

- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/homestead-20-up-problem
- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/im-unable-to-run-homestead-up?page=2

Don't know if this helps, but looking in `C:/Users/mtpultz`:

```
/.homestead
  \_ .vagrant
     after.sh
     aliases
     homestead.yaml
     mtpultz - Shortcut
/.vagrant.d
  \_ /boxes
       \_ /laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead
            \_ /0.3.0
     /data
     /gems
     /rgloader
     /tmp
     insecure_private_keys
     setup_version
/.VirtualBox
  \_ list of log files
     vbox-ssl-cacertificate.crt
     VirtualBox.xml
/VirtualBox VMs
  \_ /homestead
      \_ /logs
         box-disk1.vmdk
         homestead.vbox
  \_ /settler_default_12344848209239843
```

Using `vagrant box remove laravel/homestead --box-version=0.x.x` I removed some [older version of laravel/homestead](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/delete-vagrant-box).

What should I be doing to be able to boot up the vm so I can continue working, and not have to destroy anything?

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to **`C:/Users/mtpultz/VirtualBox VMs`** and delete the folder called **`homestead`**.

2) Run **`homestead up`** from your command prompt again.

Comment: you may also have to delete ".vagrant.d" in your user directory

Answer (score 0):

You can set a different name for your vagrant box. On top of your Homestead.yaml file you can add:

```
box: laravel/homestead-2x
```

and check if the machine boots