# Windows 10 file permission error with Github

Tags: git, github, vagrant, git-bash

I'm trying to install varying-vagrant-vagrants (vvv).
When I enter the git command:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV.git vagrant-local
```

I get

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'vagrant-local': Permission denied
```

I tried going in the security settings for my user folder and setting permissions for everyone. Help?

Comment: Where did you try to clone the repository? Try cloning it in a drive other than the c:\ drive

Comment: I only have one drive, which is C. I believe it's trying to clone into c//users/jordan

Comment: Open Explorer. Move to the directory that you wish to clone to. Then Open a command prompt in the current directory as an administrator and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, no need to use the [`git://` protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol): http(s) works just fine;

```
git clone https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV.git vagrant-local
```

Second, you will be creating vagrant-local in the current folder you are in, so make sure to do first:

```
cd %USERPROFILE%
```

Ne need for a git bash here, but should you be in a git bash, that would be:

```
cd /c/Users/jordan
```

Once the clone has succeeded, any vagrant error can be resolved with the "[A VirtualBox machine with the name '...' already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26993903/6309)" question.

Comment: Ok, I tried this, but got "A VirtualBox machine with the name 'vagrant-local' already exists.
Please use another name or delete the machine with the existing
name, and try again." The odd thing is I did delete this folder before trying to do this. This occured when I tried the vagrant up command within the folder.

Comment: @JordanCarter This no longer a git clone issue then? Meaning, the git clone did succeed, right?

Comment: @JordanCarter I have added a link in the answer to address the vagrant error message you mention.