# Delete a saved & locked zombie vm with vboxmanage

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, homestead

Using Laravel Homestead and have my first encounter with a wild zombie vm I can't destroy.

```
$Vagrant global-status
...Nothing

$vboxmanage list vms
..."homestead-7" {a00faea2-9b77-466d-beac-ab892dc0f0c9}

$vboxmanage unregistervm homestead-7 --delete
...VBoxManage: error: Cannot unregister the machine 'homestead-7' while it is locked

$vboxmanage startvm homestead-7
...VBoxManage: error: The machine 'homestead-7' is already locked by a session (or being locked or unlocked)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "LaunchVMProcess(a->session, sessionType.raw(), env.raw(), progress.asOutParam())" at line 589 of file VBoxManageMisc.cpp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kill the VBoxHeadless process and run `vboxmanage unregistervm homestead-7 --delete`.

[Similar SO question & answer found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769808/how-do-i-delete-a-virtualbox-machine-in-the-guru-meditation-error-state)